# Calculate the velocity of an object being moved manually?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm directly modifying an object position by moving it around with the mouse button.

```
Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z);
touchPosition.z = transform.position.z;

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

What I want to find out is what is the average velocity of the object in the last few frames. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably would look something like this:

```
Vector3 velocity;

Vector3 lastPosition = transform.position;
Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z);
touchPosition.z = transform.position.z;

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    transform.position = newPosition;
    velocity = (newPosition - lastPosition) / Time.deltaTime;
}
```